# subtracting datetime values in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm curently trying to subtract a datetime.datetime.now() from a DateTime column in one of my sqlalchemy tables:

```
session.query(gmos.GMOSMOSRawFITS.date_obs - datetime.datetime.now()).all()
```

it fails with despite all of the rows being normal datetime objects:

```
ValueError: Couldn't parse datetime string '-1' - value is not a string.
```

I want the minimum timedelta to now. How do I do that?

Cheers

Comment: depends very much on the type of database you're using.  not all DBs support math operations with dates.  Using echo=True will reveal what the SQL looks like and you can experiment at your SQL console with what works on that platform.